# Vuejs prevent adding new line in contenteditable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can i prevent enter from adding new line in contenteditable div.
I have tried @keyup.enter.prevent but it's not working.
also tried @keyup.enter.prevent & @keyup.enter.stop.prevent but no luck.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need `keydown` instead, when you reach the `keyup` event the browser has already inserted whatever key you pressed into the input.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div contenteditable="true" @keydown.enter.prevent>edit me</div>
</div>
```